# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to add all the JARs (including `hibernate3.jar`), but I cannot find how to solve it.

The error stack trace is as follow:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger          (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at com.mysite.InsertTestJava.main(InsertTestJava.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cache/RegionFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:236)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:327)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptorInternal(BeanWrapperImpl.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.isWritableProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more
```

In the last cause is `ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.RegionFactory`. What does that mean?

Comment: `RegionFactory` seems to be in Hibernate Core 3.3. Is that library in your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution: I removed Hibernate 3 from class path and I added Hibernate 3.5. It's working now. Both @lee and @atropo was right...